# Journey Builder, Sending first journey, how is the journey initiated?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

NEW SFMC user, First Journey:
Is the journey kicked off once it is activated and the associated emails are sent? My Entry Event is a one time email. There is no trigger, just a few follow up emails for those who open the initial email.

Please advise.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Mark, Journey Builder manages streams of communication that follow "Events", rather than a segmentation tool that defines who receives a given campaign. Think of an event as the addition of a row to a Data Extension. You'll need a Data Extension as the source of the events (new data extension rows). So, either insert the audience for the first email into that DE and fire events through Automation Studio in the step after you execute your Query Activity to insert into the Event Source DE or do some form of Send Logging from the initial email to insert rows into an event source DE.